# replace multiple occurrence in string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to replace multiple occurrence of a specific word in a string and keep only the last one.

```
   "How about a how about b how about c" to ==>
    "a b How about c"
```

I use string.replace to replace all occurence,yet I still want the last one.sorry if it's naive

Comment: You could find the index of the last expression and then move that into it's own string, perform your replace all then concat the strings back together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use some kind of loop that checks to see if anything happened..

```
function allButLast(haystack, needle, replacer, ignoreCase) {
    var n0, n1, n2;
    needle = new RegExp(needle, ignoreCase ? 'i' : '');
    replacer = replacer || '';
    n0 = n1 = n2 = haystack;
    do {
        n2 = n1; n1 = n0;
        n0 = n0.replace(needle, replacer);
    } while (n0 !== n1);
    return n2;
}

allButLast("How about a how about b how about c", "how about ", '', 1);
// "a b how about c"
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great. Deeply appreciated

Comment: @JackDre When something is helpful on _stackoverflow_, don't forget to upvote it. Then, if an answer solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as the solution.

Comment: I tried, I have only 14 now after someone downvoted :) once I get it back I'll upvote.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach, supports both RegExp and normal string needles:

```
var replaceAllBarLast = function(str, needle, replacement){
  var out = '', last = { i:0, m: null }, res = -1;
  /// RegExp support
  if ( needle.exec ) {
    if ( !needle.global ) throw new Error('RegExp must be global');
    while( (res = needle.exec(str)) !== null ) {
      ( last.m ) && ( last.i += res[0].length, out += replacement );
      out += str.substring( last.i, res.index );
      last.i = res.index;
      last.m = res[0];
    }
  }
  /// Normal string support -- case sensitive
  else {
    while( (res = str.indexOf( needle, res+1 )) !== -1 ) {
      ( last.m ) && ( last.i += needle.length, out += replacement );
      out += str.substring( last.i, res );
      last.i = res;
      last.m = needle;
    }
  }
  return out + str.substring( last.i );
}

var str = replaceAllBarLast(
  "How about a how about b how about c", 
  /how about\s*/gi, 
  ''
);

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of language, there is no built-in method to do that.
What you can do is something like (may require debugging)

```
string customReplace(string original, string replaceThis, string withThis)
{
    int last = original.lastIndexOf(replaceThis);
    int index = s.indexOf(replaceThis);
    while(index>=0 && index < last )
     {
        original = original.left(index)+ original.right(index+replaceThis.length);
        last = original.lastIndexOf(replaceThis); // gotta do this since you changed the string
        index = s.indexOf(replaceThis);
     }
     return original; // same name, different contents.  In C# is valid.
}
```